# How Can I do a Split payment using paypal

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, braintree

I am developing an IOS app with payment feature integration, App requirement is to make split payment, so that payment can divide by payment gateway only in between app owner and merchant.

So please let me know valid documentation links or reference source codes which can help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance. Appreciate all inputs.

Comment: You need to check paypal documentation before asking such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do split payment in Paypal, its just easy steps to follow and you can succeed in your implementation.

https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/overview

Comment: This is incorrect.  Check out the compatibility within Braintree's Marketplace -- "Braintree Marketplace is not compatible with PayPal"